# does jmeter repeat the recorded steps

Tags: apache, jmeter, automated-tests

Does JMeter repeat the recorded steps. For example, if I record a scenario of adding a comment to a record in a defect tracking system, and if i re-run the test using JMeter, will the same comment be added again while running the test?

Comment: You know you can try it by yourself instead of asking, but yes, it does that. You can of course use some variables to add some random messages, time stamps etc.

Answer (score 0):

it will replay exactly what you recorded so you need to find all dynamic ids that are sent and extract them from the responses using post processors to extract ids into variables and use ${varName} in your requests.